# Downloading a package from Gitlab package registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab-ci.yml file that creates a maven deployment and am trying to trigger another pipeline that takes the package from the registry and create a docker image

```
image: maven:latest

before_script:
  - mvn --version

stages:
  - build
  - trigger

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn package
    - mvn deploy 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*

trigger:
  stage: trigger
  trigger:
    project: my/other/project/repo
    branch: master
```

I'm having trouble finding out just how to get that package (or published artifacts) to the triggered pipeline. When using the container registry I just specify the image and gitlab pulls it down, not sure if I'm missing something obvious here but how do I actually use/download a package from gitlab?

I've tried to curl files in the package registry like this

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/00112233/packages/generic/io/my/package/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myfile.xml"
```

which throws the following error

```
{"error":"package_version is invalid"}
```

But when I curl GET on the package that is the package version

```
[
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "io/my/package",
    "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    "package_type": "maven",
    "status": "default",
    "_links": {
      "web_path": "/my/web/path/-/packages/00112233",
      "delete_api_path": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/0123456/packages/00112233"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-01-11T23:59:28.626Z",
    "tags": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible to use or download the packages in gitlab in another pipeline triggered?

## Additional code:

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:latest

before_script:
  - mvn --version

variables:
  PARENT_JOB_ID: myteststring # This works
  # PARENT_JOB_ID: $CI_JOB_ID # This doesn't

stages:
  - build
  - trigger

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn package
    - mvn deploy 

trigger:
  stage: trigger
  trigger:
    include: my_ci.yml
```

my_ci.yml

```
image:
  name: docker:20

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $JOB_ID # echos nothing if $CI_JOB_ID is $PARENT_JOB_ID, echos the string if it's something else
```

========================

Output from job when PARENT_JOB_ID is set to a random string

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
Using docker image sha256:15a9bc7c6340df2ac9d6c8196ca1d905180ddf2ca8b29a8d98f5422e2e5ccf85 for docker:20 with digest docker@sha256:a729cce205a05b0b86dc8dca87823efaffc3f74979fe7dc86a707c2fbf631b61 ...
$ echo "Test string = $PARENT_JOB_ID"
Test string = myteststring
```

Output from job when PARENT_JOB_ID is set to CI_JOB_ID

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
Using docker image sha256:15a9bc7c6340df2ac9d6c8196ca1d905180ddf2ca8b29a8d98f5422e2e5ccf85 for docker:20 with digest docker@sha256:a729cce205a05b0b86dc8dca87823efaffc3f74979fe7dc86a707c2fbf631b61 ...
$ echo "Test string = $PARENT_JOB_ID"
Test string =
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are using the wrong API for the situation. Since you store it in artifacts. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts

```
GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/artifacts
```

Before we use the the artifact API we firstly need the id of the job, which contains the latest artifacts, from the parent pipeline. To get this firstly we will find the id of the last pipeline (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines)

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines
```

Command:

```
PIPELINE_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>"  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines" | jq '.[0].id')
```

Next, we will use the **pipeline id** to fetch the **job id** by specifying the job name. In your case **build** .To achieve this we will use the Gitlab API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines
```

Command:

```
PARENT_JOB_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines/$PIPELINE_ID/jobs" | jq '.[] | select(.name=="build") | .id')
```

Combining all this with the artifacts API we get the following code for the child pipeline code, my_ci.yml in your case:

```
image:
  name: docker:20

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apk add jq curl
    - |
      PIPELINE_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>"  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines" | jq '.[0].id')
      PARENT_JOB_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines/$PIPELINE_ID/jobs" | jq '.[] | select(.name=="build") | .id')
      wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML,like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs/$PARENT_JOB_ID/artifacts" -O artifacts.zip
```

Comment: I publish it to package registry and as an artifact, presumably the parent pipeline and the child pipeline have different job_ids. Is there a way to pass one to the other in that case?

Comment: Maybe now this is what you need? You can get the job_id when you trigger the child pipeline

Comment: An extra addition. Seems you cant download artifacts with curl (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/214911). Used wget instead

Comment: Now having a weird problem where if PARENT_JOB_ID: $CI_JOB_ID, it won't echo in the next job. But if it's set to a random string it will. Updated my code

Comment: Care to clarify a bit more about the issue with PARENT_JOB_ID?

Comment: Added the console output above. Basically when PARENT_JOB_ID is set to a random string it works as expected, but when its set to a predefined variable (ie CI_JOB_ID) there is no output. At a loss with this

Comment: @CEamonn since it seems we are having trouble in passing the JOB ID as variable. I added another approach where we retrieve it directly throught the Gitlab API. What about this?